C++ Hypre - Solver returns unexpected result
I'm trying to use Hypre to solve a system of linear equations:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "HYPRE_krylov.h"
#include "HYPRE.h"
#include "HYPRE_parcsr_ls.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    int myid, num_procs;
    int N, n;

    int ilower, iupper;
    int local_size;

    HYPRE_IJMatrix A;
    HYPRE_ParCSRMatrix parcsr_A;
    HYPRE_IJVector b;
    HYPRE_ParVector par_b;
    HYPRE_IJVector x;
    HYPRE_ParVector par_x;

    HYPRE_Solver solver, precond;

    // Initialize
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
    HYPRE_Initialize();

    N = 6;
    local_size = N / num_procs;

    ilower = local_size * myid;
    iupper = local_size * (myid + 1) - 1;
    local_size = iupper - ilower + 1;

    HYPRE_IJMatrixCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ilower, iupper, ilower, iupper, &A);
    HYPRE_IJMatrixSetObjectType(A, HYPRE_PARCSR);
    HYPRE_IJMatrixInitialize(A);

    // Fill the matrix anti-diagonal
    {
        int nnz;
        double values[1];
        int cols[1];
        int tmp[2];

        for (i = ilower; i <= iupper; i++)
        {
            nnz = 0;
            cols[nnz] = N - i - 1;
            values[nnz] = 1;
            nnz++;

            tmp[0] = nnz;
            tmp[1] = i;
            HYPRE_IJMatrixSetValues(A, 1, &tmp[0], &tmp[1], cols, values);
        }
    }

    HYPRE_IJMatrixAssemble(A);
    HYPRE_IJMatrixGetObject(A, (void**)&parcsr_A);

    // Create the rhs and solution
    HYPRE_IJVectorCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ilower, iupper, &b);
    HYPRE_IJVectorSetObjectType(b, HYPRE_PARCSR);
    HYPRE_IJVectorInitialize(b);

    HYPRE_IJVectorCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ilower, iupper, &x);
    HYPRE_IJVectorSetObjectType(x, HYPRE_PARCSR);
    HYPRE_IJVectorInitialize(x);

    {
        double* rhs_values, * x_values;
        int* rows;

        rhs_values = (double*)calloc(local_size, sizeof(double));
        x_values = (double*)calloc(local_size, sizeof(double));
        rows = (int*)calloc(local_size, sizeof(int));

        for (i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
        {
            rhs_values[i] = i + 1;
            x_values[i] = 0.0;
            rows[i] = ilower + i;
        }

        HYPRE_IJVectorSetValues(b, local_size, rows, rhs_values);
        HYPRE_IJVectorSetValues(x, local_size, rows, x_values);

        free(x_values);
        free(rhs_values);
        free(rows);
    }

    HYPRE_IJVectorAssemble(b);
    HYPRE_IJVectorGetObject(b, (void**)&par_b);

    HYPRE_IJVectorAssemble(x);
    HYPRE_IJVectorGetObject(x, (void**)&par_x);

    HYPRE_IJMatrixPrint(A, "IJ.out.A");
    HYPRE_IJVectorPrint(b, "IJ.out.b");

    // Solve the system using PCG
    HYPRE_ParCSRPCGCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &solver);
    HYPRE_PCGSetMaxIter(solver, 100);
    HYPRE_PCGSetTol(solver, 1e-6);
    HYPRE_ParCSRPCGSetup(solver, parcsr_A, par_b, par_x);
    HYPRE_ParCSRPCGSolve(solver, parcsr_A, par_b, par_x);

    // print the local solution
    int nvalues = local_size;
    int* rows = (int*)calloc(nvalues, sizeof(int));
    double* values = (double*)calloc(nvalues, sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < nvalues; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = ilower + i;
    }
    HYPRE_IJVectorGetValues(x, nvalues, rows, values);

    for (int i = 0; i < nvalues; i++) {
        printf("Rank %d, x[%d] = %lf\n", myid, rows[i], values[i]);
    }

    // Finalize HYPRE
    HYPRE_Finalize();
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (0);
}


With N=6, the matrix A will be
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0

And vector B = 1 2 3 4 5 6
The expected result X will be 6 5 4 3 2 1
But the result I got is very strange
With mpi world size = 1, X = 1.625  3.250  4.875  6.500  8.125  9.750
With mpi world size = 2, X = 1.4  2.8  4.2  1.4  2.8  4.2
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows with Intel MPI library.
The hypre install cmake config is: cmake -S ".." -B . -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DHYPRE_ENABLE_ONEMKLBLAS=ON -DHYPRE_ENABLE_ONEMKLRAND=ON -DHYPRE_ENABLE_ONEMKLSPARSE=ON -DHYPRE_HAVE_MPI=ON -DHYPRE_WITH_MPI=ON -DHYPRE_USING_HOST_MEMORY=ON -DHYPRE_USING_HYPRE_BLAS=ON -DHYPRE_USING_HYPRE_LAPACK=ON
I tried to modify this line from
HYPRE_IJMatrixCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ilower, iupper, ilower, iupper, &A);

to
HYPRE_IJMatrixCreate(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ilower, iupper, 0, N - 1, &A);

but the results are also strange.

Please tag your question with "C" there is no "C++" in your code. Otherwise you have a lot of C++ learning to do.

I don't understand.  What's the purpose of a one or two length array, e.g. int cols[1];?  In the C and C++ languages, the arrays do not expand during runtime.

Since you tagged C++, prefer to use std::vector to dynamic memory.  The vector can easily expand during runtime and manages the memory for you.

Accessing arrays out of bounds is Undefined Behaviour (UB).  For example, the compiler can place the arrays next to each other and cols[1] will overwrite onto tmp[0].  If your code is in the same memory that the arrays are in, you could overwrite your code.

Since you tagged C++, prefer to use new to malloc.  The malloc function does not call constructors.  Also, for arrays, use new[], and remember to use delete [] as well.

What do you need the math library for?  What symbols in your code does it resolve?

You are not using the string.h library either.  Since you tagged as C++, use std::string from <string> when using text variables.

In your printing code, the Rank variable, myid, doesn't change within the loop.  You should factor out the Rank text to before the loop and remove it from within the loop.
